# black screen on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, grub2, keyboard, 16.04, encryption

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 from 15.10.  When I restarted the system, it came up with a black screen.  After searching around, I determined that the problem was with the lack of a proper Radeon driver.  I added the following line to the grub file and that seemed to solve the black screen problem.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset quiet splash"
```

However now the keyboard does not work when I try to enter the LUKS pass phrase. I am using full disk encryption.

As a workaround, I must then do a hardware reset and go to the grub screen from which I can get to the pass phrase screen and the keyboard then works. It is a clumsy way to get into Linux but it works.

Does anybody have any ideas why the keyboard does not work until I do a hardware reset?